# Hyperlink format issues inside email body

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink, smtp, mailmessage

I have a ASP.Net MVC web application which sends emails containing hyperlinks. I have never had a problem with the emails until a few weeks ago.

Recently I've had to move my application to a new hosting company, and since then I've had some trouble with the format of the hyperlinks in the emails.

Below shows an example of the method that sends the email:

```
Private sendEmail(int uID, string verifyCode)
{

//To addresses, subject etc
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
string messageBody = "";

messageBody = messageBody + "<p>Some text</p><br />";
messageBody = messageBody + "<p><a href='http://mywebsite.co.uk/uid/" + uID + "?Verify=" + verifyCode + "'>http://mywebsite.co.uk/uid/" + uID + "?Verify=" + verifyCode +"</a></p>;

mail.Body = messageBody;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

//Send email etc

}
```

Since I've moved to the new hosting company, intermittently, I've had emails coming from my software like below:

**Problem 1** - The hyperlink is displayed twice, once as expected, then again inside <> brackets. When the user then clicks on the link it obviously takes them to an incorrect URL.

Some text

http://mywebsite.co.uk/uid/2?verify=xhtajw83ns72<http://mywebsite.co.uk/uid/2?verify=xhtajw83ns72>

**Problem 2** - Sometimes the dot is left out of the web address, e.g. below the dot is missing between co and uk - again this results in an incorrect URL for the user.

Some text

http://mywebsite.couk/uid/2?verify=xhtajw83ns72

I don't understand why this code has worked for many years on my previous web server and only after I moved to the new hosting company has it been a problem, albeit, not constant and only intermittently.

Any feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: Contact your hosting company, clearly they have something tampering with the content of the email, possibly as a spam prevention measure or some such.

Comment: I intend to, but they might refuse to change their email settings etc. and in this case I'd like to know if there is anything I can do to my code to make it more foolproof.

Comment: Assuming your HTML is absolutely valid then the code is not the issue. Are you sure the issue is not on the client end? It's also possible that they have some spam prevention software or similar which is affecting the email. The first step is still to speak to your host...